# How to Align the column in center in blogspot

Tags: css, widget, blogger

Im not a programmer, im a medico, Making a medical blog. I used a template in blogspot and i adjusted the width of container to auto instead of 1000px .

[image]

Now the margin over the right side is more that in left. Please tell me how to align this  to center.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. You should add `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Comment: can you please tell me where i should make the change `body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: $(body.background.color);
  font: $(body.font);
  color: $(body.text.color);
}
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background-color: $(content.background.color);
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}`